# In ML, using RNN for an NLP project, is it necessary for DATA redundancy?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, dataset, repeat

Is it necessary to repeat similar template data... Like the meaning and context is the same, but the smaller details vary. If I remove these redundancies, the dataset is very small (size in hundreds) but if the data like these are included, it easily crosses thousands. Which is the right approach?
[SAMPLE DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qcssp.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is acutally not a question suited for stack overflow but I'll answer anyways:

You have to think about how the emails (or what ever your data this is) will look in real-life usage: Do you want to detect any kind of spam or just similiar to what your sample data shows? If the first is the case, your dataset is just not suited for this problem since there are not enough various data samples. When you think about it, every of the senteces are exactly the same because the company name isn't really valueable information and will probably not be learned as a feature by your RNN. So the information is almost the same. And since every input sample will run through the network multiple times (once each epoch) it doesnt really help having almost the same sample multiple times.

So you shouldnt have one kind of almost identical data samples dominating your dataset.
But as I said: When you primarily want to filter out "Dear customer, we wish you a ..." you can try it with this dataset but you wouldnt really need an RNN to detect that. If you want to detect all kind of spam, you should search for a new dataset since ~100 unique samples are not enough. I hope that was helpful!

Comment: Actually, the sample is only a small part of the existing dataset. My question is "Should I repeatedly add such data? " Say, I already have dataset size 700, if I have these redundancies (many such similar examples), it goes to 41000 n all. What can I do?

Comment: As I said, you shouldnt use those redundancies bc the model will primarily learn them over other features and wont perform good. So you can have redundancies but not that many (maybe 50 times or so). If you think that the dataset then is still too small you should search for a new one